# Add class dynamically from functions.php to div on singe product page - woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

On a single product page (Woocommerce) a plugin in adding the following div structure:

```
<div class="variations-table">
<div class="variation">tennis</div>
</div>
```

I would like to add `<?php $variations>` (already defined) to the "variation" class so I can style these classes depending on the name of the variation.
So the result for a variation called "tennis" should be:

```
<div class="variations-table">
<div class="variation tennis">tennis</div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this dynamically via my functions.php file, so I do not have to touch the plugin files?

Comment: Which theme is currently active?

Comment: Astra, child-theme.

Comment: There is no such `variations-table` class in Astra theme

Comment: No, it's added by the plugin.

Comment: It's a custom plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247584/discussion-between-mujuonly-and-denny).

Comment: Why don't you use the `body_class` filter to add your custom classes to the `<body>` instead? Then, you can write your CSS selectors like this: `body.my-class .variations-table {...}`

Comment: I do not think this will work, as a single product page can hold several variations ("tennis", "clothes" and "summer" for example). I would like to style the "tennis" div differently as the "summer" div.

Comment: @Denny sorry I misread your question, you are right. You should look for available filters in the custom plugin's source files and hope for the best. Alternatively you could use JS/jQuery and set these classes dynamically.

Comment: Edit the plugin files and echo the value in the class as well.